# /bin/su: Permission denied in CentOS can not set su - root

Tags: terminal, centos, root

I'm trying to set myself as a root and once I type in `su - root` in the terminal it just give me an error saying /bin/su: Permission denied so I checked the permission in that file

`-rwsr-x--- 1 root wheel 24120 Mar 30 2011 su*`

I'm wondering why I can't use this I'm trying to install some plugin and it asks me to use root thats why I needed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried using the command:
`$ sudo su`

Comment: I get this msg after tried that `myaccount is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to allow a user to switch to root, but didn't want to add the user to wheel group. Hence, I used sudoers file.

Add the following line to the sudoers file to allow `admin` user to use su

```
admin ALL= /bin/su
```

Do not edit sudoers file directly, instead use `visudo`.

Now you can switch to another user with

```
sudo su - user2
```

In my case, I added the following line to make sudo prompt for root password and not admin user's password.

```
Defaults:admin rootpw
```

Comment: It even says permission denied when I use visudo command. What to do now?

Comment: try `sudo visudo`. You need super user privilege to edit `sudoers` file

Comment: Using sudo again returns "sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250560/centos-error-sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root