# CentOS error - sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, centos, sudo

I found another question with the same headline, however, I suppose my case is a bit different.

In an attempt to setup the new project, I needed to install nodejs. I realised that it worked only when used with sudo. For eg. sudo npm

Furthermore, I visited the link https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions and performed

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

to change default directory permissions.
Now because I had to sudo npm here as well, I ran

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(sudo npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

Post this, whenever I try to use sudo, I get this error -

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

I understand that my setup for npm should have been better and off root, but I am a Linux novice.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

**More information -**

`ls -l $(which sudo)` gives =>  `---s--x--x. 1 dev root 123832 Aug 13 2015 /usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: What does `ls -l $(which sudo)` tell you?

Comment: `---s--x--x. 1 dev root 123832 Aug 13  2015 /usr/bin/sudo`
I see all files in bin have dev now. :/

Comment: Can you think hard and remember what you did that changed the owner of all the files in `/usr/bin` from `root` to `dev`?

Comment: Possibly - `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(sudo npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

Comment: Yeah.  So you didn't see where it says "WARNING: If the displayed path is just /usr, switch to Option 2 or you will mess up your permissions." on the page you linked?

Comment: I certainly did. But only after I executed the code. My bad indeed. Do you see a work around that avoids a re-image?

Comment: This is a virtual machine and recovery mode may not be possible. I am trying to avoid a reinstall.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that you probably changed permissions to the directory `/usr/bin`.

To resolve that :

1) First be sure that **root** is owner of this directory `/usr/bin` :

```
chown root:root /usr/bin
```

2) and change permission for this directory :

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

Comment: I am facing this issue: chown: changing ownership of ‘/usr/bin/’: Operation not permitted

Comment: @Baruch For your answer to work the user must know the root password i.e the password it prompts when `su -` is executed otherwise there is no way he can be executing these commands as sudo cannot be used.

Comment: I should mention that this is worth running *even* *if* `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` displays correct information.  I had `ls -l` display what's expected; I even did a `stat` to make sure that UID and GID are 0; but, running the above commands anyways (after mounting the directory on another system) ended up fixing the problem.  Even though `ls -l` and `stat` outputs have not changed one bit.  Some unix bug I guess?

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is still experiencing problems with sudo, I was able t solve it by checking the shell access of the account in WHM. I received the same error because the account had Jailed Shell restrictions. I set it to normal shell and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Issue:
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Noticed:
---s--x--x. 1 dev root 123832 Aug 13 2015 /usr/bin/sudo

user and group should be root and the sudo file should have setuid

Should be 
---s--x--x. 1 root root 123832 Aug 13 2015 /usr/bin/sudo

and also double