# CentOs: Unable to do sudo

Tags: centos, sudo

I'm currently having issue running sudo bash in CentOs environment. Everytime I call sudo give me this error **sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?**.

Currently, I have these permissions **-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 130720 Nov 20  2015 /usr/bin/sudo**.

I cannot use any sudo command and cannot use **su root** as password is not set.

All your suggestion and insights are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CentOS error - sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250560/centos-error-sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root)

Comment: It seems that the solution is not applicable to me as I cannot do any sudo commands and at the same time cannot do any commands that requires sudo.

Comment: If you don't have root access, then you may be stuck (i.e. you'll have to reinstall / recreate your instance).

Comment: Probably the wrong permissions on sudo and su. /usr/sbin/sudo needs to have +s permission. As Oliver was saying, if you do not have root access then it's tricky. You might try to boot in single user mode if you have console access and fix the permissions from there