# suid is not honoured inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, containers, suid

I downloaded sudo in my DockerFile

RUN yum -y update && 
yum -y install which sudo

I have set suid bit on it

RUN chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
RUN chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo

In container I see lot of binaries with suid bit set

root@89f28b09dee0 go]# ls -la /usr/bin/* | grep rwsr

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      73888 Aug  9  2019 /usr/bin/chage

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      78408 Aug  9  2019 /usr/bin/gpasswd

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      44264 Aug  9  2019 /usr/bin/mount

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      41936 Aug  9  2019 /usr/bin/newgrp

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      27856 Aug  9  2019 /usr/bin/passwd

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      32128 Aug  9  2019 /usr/bin/su

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root     147320 Aug  9  2019 /usr/bin/sudo

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      31984 Aug  9  2019 /usr/bin/umount

Other binaries which are part of base image works seelessly

[test@89f28b09dee0 go]$ passwd
Changing password for user test.
Changing password for test.
(current) UNIX password:

But sudo fails

sudo
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
[test@89f28b09dee0 go]$

Most of search on internet says it may be because of filesystem permission but other binaries are working fine from same location with suid bit set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CentOS error - sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250560/centos-error-sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root)

Comment: You never need `sudo` in Docker, and I'd skip this setup entirely.  (In a Dockerfile you can use `USER root` to switch the current user; when you're launching the container you can `docker run --user` with an arbitrary user ID, including root.)

Comment: @Ruchi no if u see my output for ls -la, sudo binary has right access.

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand. Actually my container require root access at runtitme. So I am creating a sudo user to execute those commands only.

Comment: You can set your container to run as `USER root` so its single process has root-level permissions.

Comment: @DavidMaze that is bigger security risk than approach I suggested above. Also right now acadamically and technically I am interested in finding put that why it is not working . I can not find any technical explanation for it.

Comment: @sachingupta did you find the answer? I am facing the same challenge