# Using sudo in podman with qemu architecture emulation leads to sudo: effective uid is not 0,

Tags: sudo, qemu, podman

I'm running a build tool and testing a package inside a podman container. The build tool and tests must not be ran as root but both parts use the system package manager which must be ran as root.

To keep both happy, I'm creating a user (called `user`) and adding it to a group (`wheel`) which is allowed to use `sudo` without a password to run the package manager.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine

RUN apk add shadow sudo
RUN echo '%wheel ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
RUN useradd --create-home --non-unique --uid 1000 --groups wheel user
```

This is working great on my native architecture:

```bash
$ podman run --arch=x86_64 -it --user=1000:wheel $(podman build -q --arch=x86_64 .) sudo whoami
root
$ podman run --arch=x86_64 -it --user=1000:wheel $(podman build -q --arch=x86_64 .) whoami
user
```

But as soon as I add qemu architecture emulation into the mix, `sudo` refuses to do anything:

```bash
> podman run --arch=ppc64le -it --user=1000:wheel $(podman build -q --arch=ppc64le .) sudo --help
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

What does this mean? Why does it have anything to do with qemu and how do I get it to stop moaning and work?

**Additional info**

```bash
~ # ls -a /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x    1 root     root        268912 Mar  1 13:55 /usr/bin/sudo
```

The same message seem to also come from messing with the ownership/permissions of `/usr/bin/sudo`. [The prescribed fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41848643/7390688) hasn't made any difference in my case.

This does work with docker instead of podman provided I set `--credential=yes` in the magic *setup qemu* command:

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes --credential yes
```

Podman has no equivalent of this step however.

N.B. I'm not juggling between users to enhance security so workarounds which compromise security are welcome. Equally welcome are other ways to become root besides sudo (I have tried `doas` and `pkexec` but they've been even more aggravating).

Comment: Am I missing something? Where is the qemu part? Or is this something to do with "podman machine" (which I've never used, so may well be)

Comment: It's hidden inside podman. Setting `--arch` to an architecture that doesn't match the host signals podman to use qemu to run the container.

Comment: Did you file this as a bug against podman? https://github.com/containers/podman/issues

Comment: I couldn't find a bug tracking it, so I filed https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/20443

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is fundamentally related to a (mis)configuration of [binfmt_misc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html).

The `sudo` command is a [setuid binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) which always executes as the root user. However, when the `sudo` binary is of a foreign architecture and gets executed by binfmt_misc through an interpreter, by default the kernel uses the permissions of the *interpreter*, which is not setuid.

There is a flag to change the behavior:

> `C` - credentials
> Currently, the behavior of binfmt_misc is to calculate the credentials and security token of the new process according to the interpreter. When this flag is included, these attributes are calculated according to the binary. It also implies the `O` flag. This feature should be used with care as the interpreter will run with root permissions when a setuid binary owned by root is run with binfmt_misc.

**If you are running podman directly on a Linux system**, and your distribution uses [systemd-binfmt](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/binfmt.d.html) (Fedora, Ubuntu), you can make overrides of the distribution files to add the flag like this:

```
for x in /usr/lib/binfmt.d/*.conf; do
    sed 's/\(:[^C:]*\)$/\1C/' "$x" | \
    sudo tee /etc/binfmt.d/"$(basename "$x")"
done
```

**If you are using podman on macOS or Windows**, your containers run on the [podman machine](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-machine.1.html) virtual machine, which is running a Fedora image. To update the virtual machine configuration, use `podman machine ssh` to enter a shell where you can run the above command.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding the nosuid option to the security_opt list when running your container with podman.

For example:

```
$ podman run --arch=ppc64le -it --user=1000:wheel --security-opt=nosuid $(podman build -q --arch=ppc64le .) sudo whoami
```

Alternatively, you can try using nsenter to enter the container's namespace as the root user, bypassing the need to use sudo.

For example:

```
$ podman run --arch=ppc64le -d $(podman build -q --arch=ppc64le .)
$ CONTAINER_PID=$(podman inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' <container_name_or_id>)
$ sudo nsenter --target $CONTAINER_PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid /bin/bash
```

Or run the container with the --privileged flag.

For Example :

```
$ podman run --arch=ppc64le -it --user=1000:wheel --privileged $(podman build -q --arch=ppc64le .) sudo whoami
```

i think this will help

Comment: Hmm, none of these really solve the issue. `--privileged` doesn't change anything. `--security-opt=nosuid` just gives me `Error: invalid --security-opt 1: "nosuid"`.  The man pages for `--security=opt` lead me to try `--security-opt=label=filetype:nosuid` which it accepts as a valid option but doesn't do anything to fix the problem. The `nsenter` thing can also be achieved more easily by using `podman exec -it --user=0 $container_id ash` but I'd rather avoid needing external podman commands .

Comment: did you try gosu ?

Comment: I did but I couldn't even get it to do privilege upgrade without qemu. Been trying to follow [this](https://github.com/tianon/gosu/issues/11) If I add the sticky bit I get a *sticky but not allowed* error and without it I get a permission error.
```
FROM alpine

RUN useradd --create-home --non-unique --uid 1000 --groups users user
RUN wget https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.16/gosu-amd64
RUN mv gosu-amd64 /bin/gosu
RUN chmod +x /bin/gosu
RUN chown root:users /bin/gosu
RUN chmod +s /bin/gosu
```

Comment: Appologies, the dockerfile in my last comment (which I'm no longer allowed to edit) should have been:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add shadow
RUN useradd --create-home --non-unique --uid 1000 --groups wheel,users user
RUN wget https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.16/gosu-amd64
RUN mv gosu-amd64 /bin/gosu
RUN chmod +x /bin/gosu
RUN chown root:users /bin/gosu
RUN chmod +s /bin/gosu
```